# How to return Future<T> result in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on switching library but my interface's `getDuration` return `Duration` and I can't change this due to meny references.
So I have to return `Duration` instead of `Future<Duration>` in `AudioPlayer` class.
Is there any way to do it?

Here is executable code that explains what I want to do.

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:async';

// This interface is hardly to modify becase this is referenced from many place.
abstract class IAudioPlayer {
  Duration getDuration();
}

// This is old library that returns `Duration`
class OldLibraryAudioPlayer {
  Duration getDuration() {
    return Duration(seconds: 1);
  }
}

// This is new library that returns `Future<Duration>`
class NewLibraryAudioPlayer {
  Future<Duration> getDuration() async {
    var completer = new Completer<Duration>();

    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1),
        () => completer.complete(Duration(seconds: 1)));

    return completer.future;
  }
}

class AudioPlayer implements IAudioPlayer {
  // OldLibraryAudioPlayer _player = OldLibraryAudioPlayer();
  NewLibraryAudioPlayer _player = NewLibraryAudioPlayer();

  @override
  Duration getDuration() {
    // I want to return Duration instead of Future<Duration>.
    return _player.getDuration();
  }
}

void main() {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  final duration = player.getDuration();
  print('$duration');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the function to `async` or directly return the result.

Example:

```
Future<Duration> getDuration() async {
  final duration = await player.getDuration();
  return duration;
}
```

or

```
Future<Duration> getDuration() {
  return player.getDuration();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just `10` seconds delayed, haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `Duration`:

```
Future<Duration> getDuration() async{ 
  final duration = await player.getDuration(); // await here
  return duration; // return your duration 
}
```

---

If you want to return `Future<Duration>`:

```
Future<Duration> getDuration() { 
  return player.getDuration(); // return Future<Duration>
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, the first method is wrong! It returns `Future<Duration>` duration, not `Duration`, please change it!

Comment: I know changing to async method work but I want to return as `Duration` not `Future<Duration>`.

Comment: @skanmera Sorry you can't do that, you'll have to use `Future<Duration>` which actually returns a `Duration`, so what's wrong in it?

Comment: I've added the problem I'm facing and an example code that explains it.

Comment: Why don't you simple change `Duration` to `Future<Duration>` in your `IAudioPlayer` class?

Comment: If I change `Duration` to `Future<Duration>` in `IAudioPlayer`, I have to change all usages to  `await` or `then`. In this example, I have to change `main` to async method and add `await` before `player.getDuration()` or use `player.getDuration().then((_){...})`.
I can modify only `AudioPlayer` class.